# How do you combine/stitch images of different sizes to one image with a size that is a power of 2?

Tags: image, textures, game-development, godot, texture-atlas

## Some context

I am working on a voxel game (like minecraft). I can not use a prebuilt texture atlas as I need to allow players to add custom blocks to the game. That's why I must create texture atlases at the runtime based on the textures provided. These textures need not be same in size (one can be 16 by 16 while other can be 64 by 64) so I can't just paste the images at a regular distance.

## Actual question

How can I combine multiple images which can be different sizes into one while cramming as much images I can, i.e., images should be as densely packed as possible and if an image can be placed at a smaller place on the final image, it should be placed there as to not use the space that may be used by other images.
The final image must be a square and its size must be the smallest power of 2. For example if there are 4 16 by 16 images, only a 32 by 32 image should be created as its enough to contain those images. But say that there were 5 images, it should create a 64 by 64 image as its the smallest size that can contain those images.
I would also need the UV values of the textures that I can map to blockfaces.

## Game engine I use

I use godot game engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Inputs

Let us say you have a series of `Image`s you want to put into your texture atlas. Let us say it is an array:

```
var images:Array
```

And the values of that array can be either:

- Image files imported as `Image`.
- Got from calling `get_data` on `Texture`s.
- `Image`s created at runtime by other means.

---

### Compiling the sizes

Now, we can get their sizes. We are going to need them in a `PoolVector2Array` (we can actually get them in a regular `Array` and convert it, but there is no need to do that):

```
var sizes:PoolVector2Array
for image in images:
    sizes.append(image.get_size())
```

---

### Computing the atlas

Once we have the sizes, we can call `Geometry.make_atlas`:

```
var atlas_data := Geometry.make_atlas(sizes)
```

The algorithm of `Geometry.make_atlas` will try to make the atlas square.

We should query what size we got:

```
var min_atlas_size:Vector2 = atlas_data.size
```

Sadly Godot does not expose a "next power of 2" function. Given the context, I believe a simple loop will do well on this case:

```
var atlas_size := 16
while min_atlas_size.x > atlas_size or min_atlas_size.y > atlas_size:
    atlas_size *= 2
```

---

### Building the atlas

**Create an atlas `Image`**

Now that we have decided the size, we can create a new `Image` for the atlas:

```
var atlas := Image.new() 
atlas.create(atlas_size, atlas_size, true, Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

As you might suspect the first two parameters are `width` and `height`. The third parameter is whether or not you want to generate mipmaps. And the last is the pixel format, the one I'm picking here has four channels (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) of 8 bits (color depth) each.

---

**Copy the input `Image`s to the atlas `Image`**

Now copy your original images to the atlas. We get the position for each one on the result we got from `make_atlas`:

```
var points:PoolVector2Array = atlas_data.points
for index in images.size():
    var image:Image = images[index]
    var point:Vector2 = points[index]
    var size:Vector2 = image.get_size()
    atlas.blit_rect(image, Rect2(Vector2.ZERO, size), point)
```

Here the `Rect2` is the area of the `Image` we want to draw (all of it).

**Note** depending on the format of the `Image` you want to draw, you may have to convert it first:

```
source.convert(Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

Also, usually, the images are imported in a compressed format that cannot be converted directly, and thus you would have to decompress first:

```
source.decompress()
source.convert(Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)
```

If the `blit_rect` line is giving you problems, try that.

---

**UV Coordinates**

By the way, you say you want UV coordinates, we should get them from the same loop:

```
var points:PoolVector2Array = atlas_data.points
var uv_scale := 1.0/atlas_size
var uv_rects := []
for index in images.size():
    var image:Image = images[index]
    var point:Vector2 = points[index]
    var size:Vector2 = image.get_size()
    atlas.blit_rect(image, Rect2(Vector2.ZERO, size), point)
    uv_rects.append(Rect2(point * uv_scale, size * uv_scale))
```

---

### Converting to `Texture`

And since you want UV coordinates, I presume this is going to be a `Texture` for some shader. So, let us make a `Texture`:

```
var texture_atlas := ImageTexture.new()
texture_atlas.create_from_image(atlas)
```

Then you should be able to set it where you need it. I leave that to you.

Comment: First of all, thanks for this amazing answer. I wasn't aware about the Geometry.make_atlas method at all. But there is one mistake I have spotted in your answer. `while min_atlas_size.x < atlas_size and min_atlas_size.y < atlas_size:
`, you have used less than sign, but it should be a greater than. It should multiply the the atlas size as long as its smaller than the min_atlas_size, not bigger.